# Does Facebook allow CORS headers?

Tags: facebook, cors, cross-domain-policy

How can I discover if Facebook allowes cross domain requests? Can I make a JavaScript which can handle a Cross Domain Request to Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about the Facebook API? Anyway:

http://www.test-cors.org

Comment: Ordinary websites almost never support [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/), it is usually used for JSON or XML APIs. But if I answered your question, feel free to accept it :)